# Deploying python application on mutiple web servers

Tags: django

I have a Django application built in our shop and currently we are moving to production that will run a apache web server.

The application will run on multiple webservers
Due to load issues.

Now, I'm really worried since it's running multiple webservers.
Issue -

The application generates unique ids for session management and maintains it locally.

Now, if a user goes to webservers-a and creates
A unique id and then in the next request goes to webservers-b he will be invalidated because the unique id created for him will be local to webservers-a.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: All applications will use the same DB? i mean, will there be an unique DB?

Comment: So, you should try to pass the session ids from one server to another throught the DB, and if you are using database-backed sessions then you have both stuffs in all servers ! (via the DB)